# Microsoft Flow not outputting the data in the table for the Azure AD column fields

Tags: json, sharepoint-list, microsoft-flow, table

I am looking to get a column data to a table in Microsoft Flow from a SharePoint List but it seems to giving the following error for the Azure AD column output for the table, while I am using the right expression.
The output JSON link from the filter / The field value that I want to use is the following: -

"Change_x0020_Originator": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
      "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|r.hardy@leeds.ac.uk",
      "DisplayName": "Robert Hardy (r.hardy)",
      "Email": "r.hardy@leeds.ac.uk",
      "Picture": "https://leeds.sharepoint.com/sites/webforms/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=r.hardy@leeds.ac.uk",
      "Department": "Innovation & Technology Services",
      "JobTitle": "Application Analyst"
    },
    "Change_x0020_Originator#Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|r.hardy@leeds.ac.uk",

I use this as body in the From field in Create a HTML page and then I tried the following expressions and they didn't worked:

item()['Change_x0020_Originator']['Value']

item()['Change_x0020_Originator']['Email']

item()['Change_x0020_Originator']['DisplayName']

item()['Change_x0020_Originator']

***All of them gives the following error and the workflow doesn't work : -***


InvalidTemplate. The execution of template action 'Select' failed: The evaluation of 'query' action 'where' expression '{ "ID": "@item()['ID']", "Request Name": "@item()['Request_x0020_Name']", "Date": "@item()?['Date_x003a_']", "Change SDG": "@item()['Change_x0020_SDG']['Value']", "Change Type": "@item()['ChangeType']['Value']", "Start Date / Time": "@item()?['Start_x0020_date_x0020__x002f__x']", "End Date / Time": "@item()?['EndDate_x002f_Time']", "Impact": "@item()['Impact']['Value']", "Impact on DR": "@item()['ImpactonDR']['Value']", "Detailed Communication Plan ": "@item()?['Detailed_x0020_communications_x0']", "Reason For Change ": "@item()?['ReasonforChange_x0028_includeeme']", "Summary": "@item()?['Summary']", "CAB Advisory to Release Manager": "@item()['CAB_x0020_Advisory_x0020_to_x002']['Value']", "CAB Notes": "@item()?['CAB_x0020_Notes']", "CAB Advisory Date": "@item()?['CAB_x0020_Advisory_x0020_Date']", "Change Completed": "@item()?['Change_x0020_Completed']", "Change Originator": "@item()['Change_x0020_Originator']['Value']" }' failed: 'The template language expression 'item()['Change_x0020_Originator']['Value']' cannot be evaluated because property 'Value' doesn't exist, available properties are '@odata.type, Claims, DisplayName, Email, Picture, Department, JobTitle'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

***Other than the Azure AD columns all the others work perfectly but can't get through this anyway. And in the following error it says that this field doesn't exist and the other Azure AD one is not coming in the error as the ones which I can use.***